# Find File differences using for loop with bash or python

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am trying to add Linux machines to ansible host file with automation script. Automation process is:

1. Ansible machine gets Linux vm list which named `LinuxVms.txt` from one of Vmware server.
2. I developed a shell script as shown below. It adds servers into the  `[all_linux_host]` tag, from `LinuxVms.txt` file. The script works when used in a single operation.

After this process, what I want to do is:

- The VM team will automatically send the `LinuxVm.txt` list to the ansible server and if the `LinuxVm.txt` file has a new IP address I need to add this IP address to the ansible hosts file, under the `[all_linux_host]` tag.

I am thinking that a `for` loop should work for this. The `for` loop has to control the new arrived `LinuxVm.txt` file and only `[all_linux_host]` tag, not all tags in ansible host file. If there is a differences between file and tag it has to find that differences and add to the `[all_linux_host]` tag.

For example

- `LinuxVms.txt`

  ```
  1.1.1.1       
  2.2.2.2           
  3.3.3.3   
  12.12.12.12
  ```
- current, ansible host file `/etc/ansible/hosts`

  ```
  [test]  
  8.8.8.8         
  12.12.12.12   
  13.13.13.13

  [all_linux_hosts]
  1.1.1.1     
  2.2.2.2
  ```

  Note that `[all_linux_hosts]` is the last section in the ansible host file.
- After for loop, the ansible host file has to be like this

  ```
  [test]  
  8.8.8.8         
  12.12.12.12   
  13.13.13.13

  [all_linux_hosts]
  1.1.1.1       
  2.2.2.2           
  3.3.3.3   
  12.12.12.12
  ```

  The order of the IP addresses is not important.

Can you help me to develop the `for` loop?

---

One time operation you don't need to consider this part.

````bsh
#!/bin/bash
sudo cp /home/vmteam/LinuxVMs.txt /home/xxx
sudo chown xxx: /home/vmteam/LinuxVMs.txt
sudo dos2unix /home/xxx/LinuxVMs.txt
awk '{print $1}' /home/xxx/LinuxVMs.txt >> ansible_host_file  ##file correction
awk '{print $2}' /home/xxx/LinuxVMs.txt >> ansible_host_file  ##file correction
sed -i 's/PublicIp//g'    /home/xxx/ansible_host_file
sed -i 's/-//g' /home/xxx/ansible_host_file
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' /home/xxx/ansible_host_file
sed -i 's/IpAddress1/ /g' /home/xxx/ansible_host_file
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' /home/xxx/ansible_host_file```
````

Comment: So you want to replace the lines after `[all_linux_hosts]` with the content of `LinuxVms.txt` when the latter file is chanced/replaced OR do you want to ADD lines, that are not present yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populate an associative array`a[".."]` keyed on the linux hosts mentioned in the vms file. Then tick off hosts seen in ansible file and print what remains in the end.

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {a[$1];next}

  $1=="[all_linux_hosts]",0 {
    if ( $1 in a ) delete a[$1]
  };1

  END {
    for (host in a) print host
  }
' LinuxVms.txt /etc/ansible/hosts
[test]  
8.8.8.8         
12.12.12.12   
13.13.13.13

[all_linux_hosts]
1.1.1.1     
2.2.2.2
12.12.12.12
3.3.3.3
```

Comment: I added same question to the stack overflow. if you add your answer there I also accept there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042511/find-file-differences-using-for-loop-with-bash-or-python. thank you btw.